# Call function every time you enter an e-mail in Sent Items - Outlook - VSTO

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I am trying to make it so that when an e-mail goes to the "Sent Items" box, it calls a function that will get the "Sent Date" of the e-mail. But it is not working. Here is the code of how it is being done to add the method to be called.

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
        try
        {
            Outlook.Stores stores = Application.Session.Stores;
            foreach (Outlook.Store store in stores)
            {
                var folder = store.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
                var items = folder.Items;
                if (items.Count > 0)
                    MessageBox.Show($"Unread items in Inbox = {items.Count}");
                items.ItemAdd += ItemsAdd;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Log.Error(exception.Message);
            throw;
        }
}
```

I am trying to make it so that when an e-mail goes to the "Sent Items" box, it calls a function that will get the "Sent Date" of the e-mail. But it is not working. Here is the code of how it is being done to add the method to be called.

[image]

---

**UPDATE**

I tried using the variable **items** as a global variable, however it keeps in theory adding the function in **sent items** but it does not call the function when entering something in **sent items**.

Code below.

```
    Outlook.Items items;

    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
        try
        {
            Outlook.Stores stores = Application.Session.Stores;
            foreach (Outlook.Store store in stores)
            {
                var folder = store.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
                items = folder.Items;
                
                items.ItemAdd += ItemsAdd;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Log.Error(exception.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to get the Sent Items folder, not Inbox like shown in your code:

```
 var folder = store.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
```

Get the Sent Items instead:

```
 var folder = store.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail);
```

Second, you must declare the source object at the global scope if you want to get event fired. Otherwise, your source object (an instance of the `Items` class) will be swiped from the heap by the garbage collector (GC). See the difference in the source code:

```
// declare the source object at the class level
Outlook.Items items;

private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
        try
        {
            Outlook.Stores stores = Application.Session.Stores;
            foreach (Outlook.Store store in stores)
            {
                var folder = store.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail);
                
                // set the reference in the code 
                items = folder.Items;
                if (items.Count > 0)
                    MessageBox.Show($"Unread items in Inbox = {items.Count}");
                // subscribe to the event
                items.ItemAdd += ItemsAdd;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Log.Error(exception.Message);
            throw;
        }
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question with the attempt using your example from the answer.

Comment: Get the Sent Items folder, not Inbox.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, that will help me a lot!